# JS error on balanced.init()

Tags: javascript, balanced-payments

1. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'debug' in
   undefined
2. a.balanced.initbalanced.js:1https://js.balancedpayments.com/v1/balanced.js
3. (anonymous function)

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src=" https://js.balancedpayments.com/v1/balanced.js"></script>
   <script>
   //balanced.init('/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP798-194-2357');
   //balanced.init('/marketplaces/TEST-MP798-194-2357');
   balanced.init('TEST-MP798-194-2357');
   </script>
   ```

Getting the same error on each of the different calls. Is my URI incorrect?

Comment: Second parameter is undefined. You need second parameter.

Comment: UPDATE balanced.init('/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP798-194-2357', {'debug':true});

Comment: @Mahmoud, please stop creating self-promotional tags.  It'd bad enough having the one, we don't need overly generic others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a documentation bug on our end. There should be a second optional parameter, but right now it's required.

Like you have figured out,

```
balanced.init('YOUR-MARKETPLACE-URI', {}); // works
balanced.init('YOUR-MARKETPLACE-URI', {'debug': true}); // turns on debugging
```

Hope this helps.